# What is a top-level window in java awt?

Tags: java, window, awt, containers, frame

I found this line on the java docs tutorial site- "A Frame is a top-level window with a title and a border". Here, what is the meaning of "top-level window"?

Answer (score 3):

A 'top-level window' or 'top level container' is something that can be shown on screen without having to add it to another component. We would start a GUI with a top level container, and then add panels and components to that TLC. E.G. of top level containers..

- **AWT** - [`Frame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html), [`Window`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html), [`Dialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html) ..
- **Swing** - [`JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html), [`JWindow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JWindow.html), [`JDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html), [`JOptionPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) ..
- **Java-FX** - [`Stage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html) (I have not used Java-FX much, so am unfamiliar with the other variants of TLCs, but see the [Java-FX API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/index.html) for other examples).

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT components in favor of Swing. As to abandoning Swing for Java-FX, I'll be unwilling to do so until Java-FX is promoted to the Java API's Java docs, and makes it into the official Java Tutorial. Sun, then Oracle, has a bad habit of hyping many technologies only to later quietly drop support & development for them.

Comment: The JavaFX equivalent would be `Stage` and `Window` (though it seems not all sub-classes are top-level windows).

Answer (score 1):

In GUI toolkits such as AWT, a top-level window is a window which is usually known to the OS (heavy-weight components).

Side note: AWT (and even Swing) is a pretty old technology. I recommend to use JavaFX where possible.

Comment: what's your source for this definition.

Comment: @Daij-Djan I don't have a specific source of definition. But I just checked the official Java tutorial and Javadoc. They have a similar view: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html

Comment: @Daij-Djan e.g. JInternalFrame (Swing) is not a top-level container.

Answer (score -1):

a window without a parent.

a window can have child windows alright and they have a parent then

Comment: e.g. Dialog (which often has a parent) is a top-level window as well

Comment: well it is different in all toolkits I know but Im willing to grant you the benefit of the doubt concerning java ;)

Comment: in my mind this definition is right still :) but it seems java seems to say 'only windows backed by separate native windows are top-level"

Answer (score -1):

Observe difference among these classes.

> Frame is top level window because it has border and title. An instance
>   of frame can have a menubar. Without those it is mere is an instance
>   of java.awt.Window class.

Window class: It has neither border not title. Window class is not attached to nor embedded within another container.

Dialog: It has border and title. An instance of the Dialog class cannot exist without an associated instance of the Frame class.

Panel: just a generic container to hold components. Its instance provides a container to which to add components.

Note: Revert me back if further clarification is required.

Comment: and? decoration don't define either.. I can have a window without anything thats still top level